# using range in array

Tags: php, arrays, range

How could I do something like this

```
$ranges = array(
    range(34, 37) => 'Group A',
    range(38, 39) => 'Group B',
    range(40, 41) => 'Group C',
);

foreach($ranges as $range_key => $range_value) {
    echo "K: ".$range_key." V: ".$range_value."\n";
}
```

I get

> Warning: Illegal offset type

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do `array('Group A' => range(34, 37))` etc.?

Comment: yes that gives me a multidimensional array and I was looking to populate just an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range()` returns an array which cannot be used as an array key. You will need to use each value in the returned array as a key, like this:

```
foreach ( range(34, 37) as $value ) {
    $ranges[$value] = 'Group A';
}
foreach ( range(38, 39) as $value ) {
    $ranges[$value] = 'Group B';
}
foreach ( range(40, 41) as $value ) {
    $ranges[$value] = 'Group C';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function make_range( $first, $last, $value, &$data_array )
{
    if ( $last < $first ) return;

    for( $index = $last; $index >= $first; --$index )
    $data_array[ $index ] = $value;

    ksort( $data_array, SORT_NUMERIC );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would help

```
$ranges = array_fill( 34, 37, 'Group A' );
print_r( $ranges );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have yours keys and values backwards

```
$ranges = array(
    'Group A' => range(34, 37),
    'Group B' => range(38, 39),
    'Group C' => range(40, 41),
);

foreach($ranges as $range_key => $range_value) {
    echo "K: ".$range_key." V: ";
    print_r($range_value)
    echo "\n";
}
```